# How to set selection date up to specific date (30 days) with THCalendarDatePicker?

Tags: ios

I'm using THCalendarDatePicker as my application's calendar, however, I am required to only allow selection of up to 30 days from current date.

Does anyone have any ideas? I only see "disable future selection", which upon toggled every upcoming days can't be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is a feature of THCalendarDatePicker. You might just have to subclass it or submit a pull request to add this feature in.

Check out the method `- (BOOL)dateInFutureAndShouldBeDisabled:(NSDate *)dateToCompare` in THDatePickerViewController.m

You should be able to modify that so that it takes into account a configurable offset (e.g. 30 days) when deciding if a date should be enabled or not.

Here is a quickly modified version that does what you are looking for:

```
- (BOOL)dateInFutureAndShouldBeDisabled:(NSDate *)dateToCompare {

NSDate *currentDate = [self dateWithOutTime:[NSDate date]];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger comps = (NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear);

//QUICK AND DIRTY MODIFIED CODE. daysInTheFutureThatAreSelectable should be a configurable property.
NSInteger daysInTheFuture;
NSInteger daysInTheFutureThatAreSelectable = 30;

daysInTheFuture = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                        fromDate: currentDate toDate: dateToCompare options: 0] day];

if (daysInTheFuture > 0 && daysInTheFuture <= daysInTheFutureThatAreSelectable) {
    return false;
}
//////////////////////////////////////

currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:comps fromDate:currentDate]];
dateToCompare = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:comps fromDate:dateToCompare]];
NSComparisonResult compResult = [currentDate compare:dateToCompare];
return (compResult == NSOrderedDescending && _disableHistorySelection) || (compResult == NSOrderedAscending && _disableFutureSelection);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you teach me what do I need to do to subclass this? Cause currently this file is under my Pod, I have never tried subclassing a framework before

Comment: The easiest way would be to not use a Pod and just copy THDateDay and THDatePickerViewController files into your project. Then just modify or subclass directly. Downside is that you won't get any new updates. A slower but better way would be to make your own fork of THDatePickerViewController, make the changes on that fork and submit a pull request so everyone can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the message, I sent a feature enhancement request and they responded very swiftly. Thanks for giving an idea on what to do in the first place :)